# How to turn Pandas group into SparseDataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a tall (2743470 rows, 2 cols) DataFrame, call it df, with the following columns, integer indexed:

```
| item | user |
| 1    | abc  |
| 15   | abc  |
| 3    | def  |
```

I know there are 35605 possible item IDs and 53690 users in total. What I'd like to do is convert it to a SparseDataFrame each row represents a user, a column represents an an item, and the value is 1 wherever a user is associated with an item in the original table.

I've tried doing a group by but at that point I can't figure out how to vectorize the rest. The best I've got is the following:

```py
ids = pandas.Index(df.item.drop_duplicates())
g = df.groupby('user')
arr = []
arr_i = []
for name, group in g:
    arr_i.append(name)
    s = pandas.Series({val: 1 for val in group.item}, index=ids).to_sparse()
    arr.append(s)
book_reads = pandas.SparseDataFrame(arr, index=arr_i)
```

But even this fails with:

```py
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I tried taking out the index param to SparseDataFrame or making it a set of integers instead of strings, but to no avail. The only thing that worked is making a regular DataFrame first and then calling to_sparse on it, but that eats far too much memory.

Is there a way to vectorize this operation while using only sparse data structures?

**UPDATE**

I've also tried faking a value column of all 1's and pivoting, but almost immediately get a memory error, likely because pivot produces a dense DataFrame.

Comment: what for are you building this pivot? may be it's an XY problem, and you don't need it at all?

Comment: Trying to get a large-scale vis of the density of users vs items initially. Later, looking to get the co-occurrence matrix of items for things like basket analysis. Could very well be I should step out of Pandas to do it, but wanted to make sure the Sparse data structures couldn't help me first.

Comment: Don't know what is vis. For basket analysis, it is a clustering method, and I am pretty sure all cluster methods can deal with your initial data without need of pivot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will a memory issue with this, as the final result won't be that big (and so the unstack won't blow up)

```
In [14]: df.groupby('user')['item'].apply(lambda x: Series(1,index=x)).unstack()
Out[14]: 
      1   3   15
user            
abc    1 NaN   1
def  NaN   1 NaN

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Unfortunately with about 13 GB free going into this step, I get aMemoryError. Switching to SparseSeries does the same. It seems to happen fast too, and when monitoring RAM usage I don't seem to be anywhere near out of memory. Line it dies on is: new_values = np.empty(result_shape, dtype=dtype).

Comment: just do it iteratively then, e.g. do a section, repeat, do a section, then join the resulting frames.

Comment: Yea. That's my fallback. I'm not a Pandas expert so I wanted to make sure there wasn't some nifty way to use Sparse and do it all in one go . Thanks.

Comment: The issue is creating it. You effectively need a dense repr first to do it efficiently. You *could* do this iteraveily, but its not too efficient to iteratively updated a SparseDataFrame in place. much better to chunk this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to sparsify series before passing them to SDF, it will do it for you (not sure that you'll avoid memory error with that):

```
>>> series = [pandas.Series({val: 1 for val in group.item}, index=ids) 
...              for name, group in g]
>>> idx = [name for name, _ in g]
>>> pandas.SparseDataFrame(series, index=idx, columns=ids)
     1   15  3
abc   1   1 NaN
def NaN NaN   1
```

Comment: +1 for the shorter code, but MemoryError still persists because the Series eat up RAM before the DataFrame can make them Sparse.

Comment: @PeterParente As a workaround, you can probably try to do build result dataset in chunks.

Comment: Ha. Jeff just said as much below moments ago. Sounds like that's the only approach. As I said there, I'm not a Pandas expert so I wanted to make sure there wasn't some nifty way to use Sparse and do it all in one go.

Comment: Oh, I can't be referenced as expert in sparse part of pandas :) I'm pretty sure you can build a scipy sparse matrix for your needs, though I'm not yet sure if you need it at all (see comments below your question).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this simple iterative code took about 30s on my Mac constructing the sparse matrix I was seeking. It's not an answer to my "How do I do it with pandas?" question, but it might be useful anyway.

```
mat = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((len(users),max(ids)+1))
for i, (name, group) in enumerate(g):
    mat[i, group.item] = 1
```